# App keeps crashing and Logcat states "lateinit property todoAdapter has not been initialized"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

This is the Main activity for a simple todo list app if you want to see more of the code then please let me know

When private lateinit var todoAdapter: TodoAdapter is removed app no longer crashes but the app will no longer show the todo item on the recycler view

```
"package com.example.todoit

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.todoit.data.Todo
import com.example.todoit.data.TodoViewModel
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var todoAdapter: TodoAdapter
    private lateinit var todoViewModel: TodoViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        rvTodoItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        rvTodoItems.adapter = todoAdapter

        btnAddTodo.setOnClickListener {

            val todoTitle = etTodoTitle.text.toString()
            if (todoTitle.isNotEmpty()) {
                val todo = Todo(0,todoTitle,false)
                etTodoTitle.text.clear()
                insertDataToDataBase()
                todoAdapter.addTodo(todo)
            }
        }
        btnDeleteTodo.setOnClickListener {
            todoAdapter.deleteDoneTodos()
        }
    }

    private fun insertDataToDataBase() {
        val todoTitle = etTodoTitle.text.toString()

        if(inputCheck(todoTitle)) {

            val todo = Todo(0, todoTitle, isChecked = false)
            //Add data to database
            todoViewModel.addTodoToDataBase(todo)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill out all fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }




    private fun inputCheck(todoTitle:String):Boolean {
        return !(TextUtils.isEmpty(todoTitle))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to initialize your todoAdapter, you need to initialize todoAdapter before calling it.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var todoAdapter: TodoAdapter
    private lateinit var todoViewModel: TodoViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        todoAdapter = TodoAdapter() // if TodoAdapter requires parameters you need to pass them
        rvTodoItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        rvTodoItems.adapter = todoAdapter

        btnAddTodo.setOnClickListener {

            val todoTitle = etTodoTitle.text.toString()
            if (todoTitle.isNotEmpty()) {
                val todo = Todo(0,todoTitle,false)
                etTodoTitle.text.clear()
                insertDataToDataBase()
                todoAdapter.addTodo(todo)
            }
        }
        btnDeleteTodo.setOnClickListener {
            todoAdapter.deleteDoneTodos()
        }
    }

    private fun insertDataToDataBase() {
        val todoTitle = etTodoTitle.text.toString()

        if(inputCheck(todoTitle)) {

            val todo = Todo(0, todoTitle, isChecked = false)
            //Add data to database
            todoViewModel.addTodoToDataBase(todo)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill out all fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }




    private fun inputCheck(todoTitle:String):Boolean {
        return !(TextUtils.isEmpty(todoTitle))
    }
}
```

Comment: I added that and now it says no parameter for size and init when I pass a mutable list parameter "todoAdapter = TodoAdapter(mutableListOf(todo))"

Comment: the error in the fragment or the adapter ?

Answer (score 0):

The error clear your todoAdapter not initialzed you have to initialize before using like this :

```
todoAdapter=TodoAdapter(yourprams) 


        rvTodoItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        rvTodoItems.adapter = todoAdapter

        btnAddTodo.setOnClickListener {

            val todoTitle = etTodoTitle.text.toString()
            if (todoTitle.isNotEmpty()) {
                val todo = Todo(0,todoTitle,false)
                etTodoTitle.text.clear()
                insertDataToDataBase()
                todoAdapter.addTodo(todo)
            }
        }
        btnDeleteTodo.setOnClickListener {
            todoAdapter.deleteDoneTodos()
        }
    }
```